# jQuery - append

Tags: jquery, javascript, append

Сегодня произошла такая проблема: до этого спокойно использовавшийся `append` после перемещения нескольких строк кода *внезапно* перестал работать. Я не нашёл причины и попробовал сначала сделать эталонный тестовый простой пример:
`test.html`:

```
<html>
<head>    
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  exist
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`test.js`:

```
$('.container').append('Test');
```

И даже он не работает. Скажите, что конкретно в этом примере может быть неправильно? Я в упор не понимаю, что за фигня произошла.

Comment: [Работает же](http://jsfiddle.net/7fmxY/). Проверьте пути, имена файлов.

Comment: @Khvorostin, там немного по-другому исполняется и `div` успевает появиться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На момент загрузки `test.js` `.container` еще не существует =)

Это не считая того, что принято текст вставлять методами текстовыми (`.html(), .text()`), но это мелочь.

Comment: Точно, огромное спасибо, я опять забыл про этот подводный камень JS, который я больше всего ненавижу.  
До этого append был в колбэке $.ajax, и, соот-но, ему давалось немного задержки.
Потом я перенёс его наружу, и там он перестал работать)) спасибо.  
Про второе замечание: это для примера, в самой программе я вставляю картинку.

Comment: @Construct на самом деле, проблема не в JS, а в вашем безнадежно PHP'шоком мозке :)

Comment: Опять же поддерживаю (как в каком-то вопросе где написали array.length() :))

Comment: @AlexWindHope, не стоит сразу судить меня потому, что я занимаюсь PHP. Но это уже другая история...

Comment: Кстати, у меня тоже была такая проблема. Так и не решил. А теперь все сделал. Спасибо!